# ASP.NET MVC3 Client Side Validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation, user-interface

My client side validation is not working after installing jquery datatables, jquery ui in my project. The packages.config for the project is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jquery.datatables" version="1.9.4" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.10.3" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="jQueryUIHelpers.Mvc3" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="2.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
</packages>
```

Each time i click on a button, it POSTs even if a required field on the form in missing. Where am i going wrong? Is there any dependency issue?

Comment: If you view the generated hteml source, do your input fields have data-* attributes on them?  Also, are you using the Html helpers to generate your form fields?

Comment: Ya found it. The jQuery version jquery-1.4.4 is needed for the default jquery validate that ships with vs2010 to work. I tried upgrading the jquery validate using nuget, but no luck to work with the latest jQuery. Now i have to load 2 versions of jquery :(. Any help would be great.

Comment: Ok, so the input elements do have data-* attributes?  Then that means that the validation is working correctly on the server side, and the problem is on the client-side.  Validation does not require the old version of jQuery, so you probably have something odd.. I notice you are using jQuery 2.0.2, you do know that the 2.0 branch doesn't work with older browsers like IE8, right?  you need jQuery 1.9 branch.

Comment: Ya validations are working fine on server side. Using the old version of jquery fixed the issue, i am testing on chrome, firefox and IE9. Thanks bro for the update on compatibility m pretty new to this :)

Comment: Using the old jQuery doesn't "fix" the issue, it hides the issue.  You will likely run into other problems related to this if you don't find out what the real problem is.

Comment: How can i drill down on this? Changing the jquery version made things work, is there a new version of validate that would help?